# How can I run JavaScript after the HTML is loaded, but before it's drawn?

Tags: javascript, html

***PROBLEM:***
I have a JS script that replaces any occurrences of a certain class (".inserter"), with HTML fetched from another file (e.g., a banner and navigation bar).

Right now, using the "window.onload" event. It seems that it renders the unaltered HTML first, then makes the replacements a split-second later, resulting in an ugly flash.

I want a way to make all the **replacements first** and **then render** the final HTML. And to do this it will need access to the DOM.

***ATTEMPTS:***
I've tried using "async", "defer", "DOMContentLoaded" and a few other things that I don't remember. None of them have worked.

Is there a way to do this with vanilla JS and HTML that doesn't involve first making the body element invisible with CSS?

***EDIT:***
I was originally avoiding hiding the body with CSS because I wanted the script to be as self contained as possible. But I've figured out a way to make it work. (I have answered my own question below).

Comment: What's the problem with making the body `display: none` via a class name (or whatever) and then making it visible when your script completes? Simple to do, and pretty sure-fire.

Comment: I suspected it would cause a blank-white-screen flash. Apparently it does not, but it has the same result as everything else I've tried. It flashes with the unaltered HTML. :(

Comment: I tried it again a bit differently:

Before, I put the line that shows the body at the end of the script.

This time I put it the ".then()" function. It seems there is slight delay with the fetch function. Long story short, it works.

Comment: You need to have the code that changes the body style to be visible run when all the extra content has been loaded and installed in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a simple way to do this without without some CSS.
The easiest solution I have found so far, is to actively prevent the HTML from rendering until you've made your changes. A self-contained and compact way to do this is to:

Run the script from the head without defer, then in the script, add a style tag to the head that hides the body. After that, use the "window.onload" or similar event to make all the changes first, and then remove the temporary style tag from the head.

```js
document.head.innerHTML += ('<style id="inserter-screen-flash-prevention"> body {display: none}; </style>');
    
window.onload = () => { insertAll() };

function insertAll() {
  //...make all replacements...
  document.head.querySelector("#inserter-screen-flash-prevention").remove();

}
```

If you are using fetch, make sure to do the removal in the ".then" part of the fetch function.

Comment: Another thing you can do is have the CSS rule `body { display: none; }` and then `body.ready { display: block; }` and at the end of your initial updates you can add the "ready" class to the body tag.

Comment: Or just add `style="opacity: 0"` to the body and run `document.body.style.opacity = ''` after the load event?

Comment: @somethinghere, If you mean hard coding the opacity into the CSS, I was trying to avoid that. I wanted to be able to copy and paste my script into any project with minimal editing. Although, your suggestion might be much easier for anyone else with this question. thx